# Unity: Can a non-monobehavior class initialize a List of monobehavior objects?

Tags: list, class, object, unity-game-engine, initialization

I am having trouble initializing a List of monobehavior objects inside a non-monobehavior class. I was wondering if this is something that cant be done or if my problem is elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: How could we possibly know what have you tried if you don't post your code?

Answer (score 0):

As @Galandil commented, it is difficult to know a solution if there is not an attempts code, or at least a better explanation.

With the lack of details given: Yes, you can initialize a List of MonoBehaviours on a C# class that does not inherit from MonoBehaviour.

```cs
using UnityEngine; // It is imperative to include this namespace if you don't want to use dot notation.
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// If you give this attribute to a class, the Editor will try to serialize it on the inspector.
//But for that, it should be an attribute from either a MonoBehaviour or a ScriptableObject.
[System.Serializable]
public class Holder
{
    private List<MonoBehaviour> _monos;

    public List<MonoBehaviour> monos
    {
        get
        {
            if(_monos != null) _monos = new List<MonoBehaviour>();
            return _monos;
        }
    }
}
```

But more detail it is needed, like a justification, why having a List of MonoBehaviours on a class that won't necessarily be persistent if not referenced on a GameObject entity? Why not using ScriptableObjects, for example? Why not sticking with a Empty GameObject entity with a MonoBehaviour script with the aforementioned List?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use an explicit constructor for a MonoBehaviour. i e.

```
myMono= new MyMonoClass() ; // will not work
```

Instead, ask unity to create them via AddComponent which makes sense as Unity's component system very much needs to beaware of everymono, if you could create them atwill, they would not have a transform, they would not have callbacks, they would not have update and their coroutines would not work.

you may want them all on a single object, maybe on multiple, maybe you'll need to spawn gameobjects first, fortunately you can create those in a usual manner, so you can do somethin like

```
myMonoList.Add(new GameObject().AddComponent<MyMonoClass>());
```

You can also copy (instantiate) existing objects